# How does the const char* and string comparison work in C++?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, stdstring

Consider the following code snippet:

```
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    std::string str = "Hello";
    const char *cstr = "Hello";
    if (cstr == str) {
        std::cout<<"Both are same string.";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I am having difficulty guessing how the const char* and string comparison work:

```
if (cstr == str) {
```

As per my understanding, the overloaded operator of the left operand (**cstr** in this case) is called with **str** as the argument. Now there is no overloading of **==** for const char*. So how does the above comparison even work?

Had the comparison been **str==cstr**, I would have no issues accepting it (as == for std::string is overloaded and it accepts const char* as an argument for comparison).

Note:- I am using gcc-4.8.1 for compiling the above code.

Comment: There *is* [an overload](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_cmp) for that.

Comment: There is no "overloaded operator of the left operand", because the type of the left operand (`cstr`) is not based on an object.

Comment: @juanchopanza That's an answer.

Comment: @Angew A "read the docs" answer. I don't want to be an enabler for people who can't look stuff up. At least not this morning ;-)

Comment: Are you perhaps unaware that a non-member function can overload `==` as long as at least one of the arguments is a `class`/`struct` type?  That's why the 7th overload at juanchopanza's link can apply.  It's true that the `string` class can't have a member `operator==` invoked when the left-hand-side argument is a `const char*`....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> As per my understanding, the overloaded operator of the left operand (cstr in this case) is called with str as the argument. Now there is no overloading of == for const char*.

The operator is actually for std::string, and looks conceptually similar to this:

```
bool operator==(const char* const lhs, const std::string& rhs);
```

(though it reality it is templated).

This operator of std::string is added specifically for the operation you mention (comparing a std::string with a char*, when the char* is provided as the left-hand-side operand in the comparison).

> Had the comparison been str==cstr, I would have no issues accepting it (as == for std::string is overloaded and it accepts const char* as an argument for comparison).

Both are present (specifically to support this situation).

Answer (score 3):

From http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_cmp.

Compare a basic_string object and null-terminated array of T

```
template< class CharT, class traits, class Alloc >
bool operator==(const CharT* lhs, const basic_string<CharT,Traits,Alloc>& rhs);
template< class CharT, class traits, class Alloc >
bool operator==(const basic_string<CharT,Traits,Alloc>& lhs, const CharT* rhs);
```

...

Comment: Note that even if this function didn't exist, the comparison would be legal because if the operands of `==` are different then it looks for implicit conversions from one to the other; and `char const *` can implicitly convert to `std::string` because the latter has a non-explicit constructor taking `char const *`.